# If condition in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Oracle SQL**

I need to check a condition (a flag) and then execute the SQL codes.

What is the syntax to go about it. I saw some documents, it says we need to declare procedure, can someone help me get that syntax and with this.

E.g:

```
IF Flag = 1
    BEGIN
      select  productgroup,...
      from 
      join.. on 
      where
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        select  product
        from 
      join.. on 
      left join .. on
      where
    END
```

Comment: Be more specific on what you want. Do you want to create a PL/SQL Function/Method? Do you want your query to return conditional data?

Comment: have a look at http://plsql-tutorial.com/, for eg

Comment: Want to return conditional data.. As in if the flag is 1, it should run the first query and return the data, if not, run the second query in the else condition and display the result

Comment: What is the problem with the syntax which you have shown?

Comment: First off, PL/SQL Syntax is `IF [CONDITION] THEN ... END IF;`

Comment: Your syntax looks like SQL Server's or even Sybase's. Oracle's is quite different from that.

Answer (score 0):

within your PL/SQL block,

`IF Flag = 1 THEN
      select  productgroup,...
      [INTO {variables here}]
      from 
      join.. on 
      where ...;
ELSE
        select  product
      [INTO {variables here}]
        from 
      join.. on 
      left join .. on
      where ...;
END IF;`

Mind that your queries might need the INTO clause, if you want to assert the return values. However, in order to use this structure, you must be sure your query will return 1 and 1 only row. No more, no less.

If you need your values as a collection of rows, then you must decalre a cursor.

--> this is just an anonymous block. Not a procedure or function.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR C1 IS
    [YOUR FIRST QUERY HERE];

  CURSOR C2 IS
    [YOUR SECOND QUERY HERE];

[other variables]
BEGIN

 IF Flag = 1 THEN
   FOR REC_C1 IN C1 LOOP
     ....
   END LOOP;
 ELSE
   FOR REC_C2 IN C2 LOOP
     ....
   END LOOP;
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Also note in the example above - the scope of the variables REC_C1 and REC_C2 are only for the LOOP structures themselves.

Answer (score 0):

```
PROCEDURE check_condition (p_flag IN NUMBER)
IS
v_num NUMBER;
BEGIN

IF p_flag=1 THEN

SELECT COUNT(1)
  INTO v_num
  FROM table1
 WHERE 1=0
    AND ROWNUM=1;

    IF  v_num=0 THEN

    raise_application_error(-20101,'ERROR');
    END IF;

ELSIF p_flag=2 THEN
 NULL;
ELSE
NULL;
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: using count() you cant get too_many_rows or no_data_found and if you need only check then rownum = 1  is just in time and your values always will be 1/0;